# Как узнать на сколько процентов отображен Item из RecycleView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать на сколько процентов отображен Item из RecycleView?

Например, в этом коде я могу получить номер первого и последнего элементов отображенных на экране. Даже если они не полностью выведены на экран:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewGroup;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapterV;
        private LinearLayoutManager llm = null;

        recyclerViewGroup = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(myContext);
        recyclerViewGroup.setLayoutManager(llm);
        adapterV = new AdapterV(dataVerticals, myContext, new MyCallbackAllObject() {
            @Override
            public void callbackCall(Object object, String command) {
            }
        });
        recyclerViewGroup.setAdapter(adapterV);

        recyclerViewGroup.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                Log.i("tester", "onScrollChange: ПЕРВЫЙ ВИДИМЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ " + llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
                Log.i("tester", "onScrollChange: ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ВИДИМЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ" + llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition());

            }
        });
```

К ViewHolder могу добраться так recyclerViewGroup.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)

А как получить процент на сколько видны первые и последние элементы? Буду благодарен за любые идеи. Суть задачи, затемнять элементы по мере их ухода за экран.

Comment: Для чего это вам?

Comment: Чтобы при скроле, элементы которые не полность видны, постепенно затемнялись. Затемнение пропорционально отображаемое площади элемента. Проблема в том что с краев могут быть как целые елементы так и их куски. Положить вьюхи с градиентом неподходит

Comment: возможно вам стоит попробовать использовать анимацию с затемнением на первом и последнем айтеме, как в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714138/7566397)(но здесь другая анимация и только на первый айтем), а не вычислять проценты видимости айтемов.